# Underline an HTML ellipsis

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I am using `text-overflow: ellipsis` to clip text that is inside of a span that is inside of an anchor.  The ellipsis character is not underlined when I hover which causes a small gap.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - set `text-decoration: none` and instead of that use `border-bottom` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/544tX/1/)

```css
a {
    display: block;
    width: 185px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: This way feels like a hack, but I suppose it may be the only way to do it.  I really feel that the ellipsis should take on the `text-decoration` of the element containing it.

Comment: the ellipsis is a pseudo element here ( like `:before` or `:after` ) so it doesn't count as text. That's why the `**text**-decoration` not getting applied.

Comment: Thanks for the hack)

Answer (score 2):

If some one find this, like me, and do not like the fact that the border-bottom line is too far away this code might help [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a7eLnzym/6/)

```css
a {
    display: block;
    width: 185px;
    background: beige;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
}

a:hover::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Still a hack, but you know... :)