# Text-decoration: underline not applying with inline-block span elements

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I'm having an issue with `text-decoration: underline` on two spans that use `inline-block`. The [problem is only one part of the URL will underline when hovered, the other does not. I need to keep the display property, otherwise `text-overflow` won't get applied (see: [Text-overflow: ellipsis alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804418/text-overflow-ellipsis-alignment-issue))

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="details" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"> 
   <h2>
       <a class="heading" href="/product/acmesw" title="Acme Super Widget">
           <span class="trunc" itemprop="name">Acme Super Widget 3000</span>
           <span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">- <meta itemprop="currency" content="AUD" /><spanitemprop="price">$199.95</span></span>     
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.details {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.trunc {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width:60%;
}

h2 span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:red;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7p8w/2/

Comment: The core of the problem is that your `.trunc` is not *inheriting* `text-decoration: underline` from its parent `<a>`. You can simply add `.trunc { ..; text-decoration: inherit; .. }`. I don't know if you'll be happy with the result though, as the ellipsis still won't have the underline... I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Re: the ellipsis underline problem - it's been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903766/underline-an-html-ellipsis) and it looks like the only solution is to use `border-bottom` instead of `text-decoration: underline`. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `border-bottom` to underline the text?

```
a {
     text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue; /*Remove this if you want it only on hover*/
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color:red;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bYS9/)

Comment: Do you know any tricks to reduce the gap beneath the text and the border to match what text-decoration does since you cannot have negative padding?

Answer (score 12):

By [CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props), the underline does not affect inline blocks inside the element for which `text-decoration: underline` has been set.

You can make them underlined by explicitly setting that for them, for example by replacing the selector `a:hover` in your last CSS rule by the selector list `a:hover, a:hover *`.

This will not affect the ellipsis symbol, though. It is not part of any element content but inserted by a browser, so I don’t think you can underline it.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit weird though...

add these css?

## CSS

```
.details h2{
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff; /*use the same color as your .details background color*/
}
.details h2:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
}
```

See DEMO on jsfiddel...http://jsfiddle.net/c7p8w/14/

Comment: Thanks but you get the space between the spans and I'd prefer the line to go full length.